# Displaying Error in a View

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

Is there any standard practice to display errors in a view? Currently it is being displayed from TempData.

I implemented a derived a class from Base Controller and used that derived class in every one of my controller. Then assign error or success messages from controller.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get { return (string) TempData[CommonHelper.ErrorMessageKey]; }

        set
        {
            if (TempData.ContainsKey(CommonHelper.ErrorMessageKey))
            {
                TempData[CommonHelper.ErrorMessageKey] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData.Add(CommonHelper.ErrorMessageKey,value);
            }

            TempData.Remove(CommonHelper.SuccessMessageKey);
        }
    }

    public string SuccessMessage
    {
        get { return (string)TempData[CommonHelper.SuccessMessageKey]; }

        set
        {
            if(TempData.ContainsKey(CommonHelper.SuccessMessageKey))
            {
                TempData[CommonHelper.SuccessMessageKey] = value;
            }
            else
            {
                TempData.Add(CommonHelper.SuccessMessageKey, value);
            }

            TempData.Remove(CommonHelper.ErrorMessageKey);
        }
    }
}
```

**CommonHelper Class**

```
public class CommonHelper
{

    public const string SuccessMessageKey = "successMessage";

    public const string ErrorMessageKey = "errorMessage";


    public static string GetSuccessMessage(object data)
    {
        return data == null ? string.Empty : (string) data;
    }


    public static string GetErrorMessage(object data)
    {
        return data == null ? string.Empty : (string) data;
    }

}
```

**Then created a partial view having this**

```
@using Web.Helpers

@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CommonHelper.GetSuccessMessage(TempData[CommonHelper.SuccessMessageKey])))
{
<div class="alert alert-success">
    @CommonHelper.GetSuccessMessage(TempData[CommonHelper.SuccessMessageKey])
</div>
}
else if   (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(CommonHelper.GetErrorMessage(TempData[CommonHelper.ErrorMessageKey])))
{
<div class="alert alert-success">
    @CommonHelper.GetErrorMessage(TempData[CommonHelper.ErrorMessageKey])
</div>
}
```

**And in every view, the partial view is rendered.**

```
<div>
        @Html.Partial("_Message")
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty common implementation of displaying errors.

Controller

```
public class UserController : Controller 
{
     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Create(User model)
     {
         //  Example of manual validation            
         if(model.Username == "Admin")
         {
            ModelState.AddModelError("AdminError", "Sorry, username can't be admin")
         }

         if(!ModelState.IsValid() 
         {
            return View(model)
         }
     }
}
```

Model

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public string Username {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   // Form Html here 
}
```

You don't need all of the infrastructure you created.  This is handled by the framework.  If you need a way to add success messages you can checkout the Nuget Package MVC FLASH

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use ModelState.AddModelError()